# Is it possible to like a tweet with the Apache Camel Twitter component

Tags: apache-camel, twitter4j

[The official Apache Camel Twitter Component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/twitter.html) doesn't seem to mention liking or favoriting a tweet.

It uses Twitter4j, so I suppose it should be possible.

What I have so far:

```
//like a tweet
        from("direct:likeTweet")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .recipientList(simple("twitter://favorites/create.json?id=" +
                        "${body.tweetId}"  +
                        "&consumerKey=" + consumerKey +
                        "&consumerSecret=" + consumerSecret +
                        "&accessToken=" + accessToken +
                        "&accessTokenSecret=" + accessTokenSecret))
                .log("Response: ${body}");
```

This builds the following endpoint:

```
twitter://favorites/create.json?accessToken={redacted}&accessTokenSecret={redacted}&consumerKey={redacted}&consumerSecret={redacted}&id={redacted}
```

This produces the following error:

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: ... 

There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{id={redacted}}]
```

The error is quite clear, but unfortunately I'm not able to solve it,
since the documentation doesn't mention this functionality (to my knowledge).

Thank you!

Comment: You could use postman to see if the error come from the parameters of your request, or from apache-camel

Comment: Camel transforms this endpoint. This isn't really how you would post a request to the twitter API using Postman. You would OAuth 2.0 in the Authorization tab. The authorization would be done with a header, not as parameters in your URL.